# Is it possible to trigger a phone call when a client places an order in a WordPress/WooCommerce site and selects a specific pick-up point?

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce, triggers, call

We run a small food business and have a nice website but still most of our sales are done over the counter. Either in the production plant or in the shop. Hence we check the e-mail not that regularly and sometimes are surprised when a client (that placed and payed an order half an hour ago) arrives to our premises and claims the products immediately. We need to bake them and pack them and this takes 10 minutes which is seen as a lot for somebody who did the work on-line with enough anticipation. The perfect solution will include also directing the mail to the right address based on the selected pick-up point.

Something like: "when order placed, if pick-up point A-> mail:x & phone:1; if pick-up point B-> mail:y & phone:2; otherwise-> mail:z & phone:3"

Thanks a lot in advance, kind regards and best wishes for 2020!
Eduardo

Comment: Automated phone calls (with automated voice output) is.. seriously over the top for this, especially with regards to costs for consulting / development / setup. A regular webserver won't be able to. What is more cost-effective could be a small Telegram bot posting received orders in separate channels per pick-up point (the phone won't ring, but at least you have a notification sound). Another way would be to develop an AJAX-based web view upon WP/WooCommerce that lists paid orders so you could set up a screen for orders in your premises cycling with a Raspberry Pi auto-refreshing this view.

Answer (score 0):

Check Twilio outbound calls 
https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-make-outbound-phone-calls-php

You can use zippier api with Twilio from your wordpress to conditionally trigger an sms or a outbound a phone call